# Dropping columns or rows while reading excel

Tags: c#, excel, exceldatareader

I use the following code to loop through the excel sheet using ExcelDataReader.

```
private void GetExcelSheetData(IExcelDataReader reader)
    {
        do
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    Debug.Log(reader.GetString(i));
                }

                Debug.Log(" row is over " + rowNumber);
            }
        } while (reader.NextResult());
    }
```

This code works fine. However, I'm looking forward to dropping or skipping some rows as well as the columns. How do I manage to do so? I'm trying to read between row 3 to row 9 and column 4 to 15.

Comment: `if( /*your condition*/ ) { continue; }` ?

Comment: Use `if` statement

Comment: May I know if i would indicate the row number or the column number?

Comment: I'm trying to read between row 3 to row 9 and column 4 to 15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `if` statement, along with variables that point to current row and column:

```
    private static void GetExcelSheetData(IExcelDataReader reader)
    {
        do
        {
            int rowNumber = 0;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (rowNumber >= 3 && rowNumber <= 9)
                {
                    for (int i = 4; i <= 15; i++)
                    {
                        Debug.Log(reader.GetString(i));
                    }
                    Debug.Log(" row is over " + rowNumber);
                }
                rowNumber++;
            }
        }
        while (reader.NextResult());
    }
```

Is this what you need?